# Junit testing for complex math formulas

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, junit, tdd

I am writing an android app in Kotlin that will be calculating various geometry and physics problems.  I want to use a Test Driven Development approach but am having difficulty in determining exactly what to test with a given formula.  The following is a simple example:

I want to compute the hypotenuse for a right triangle with the following function and write junit tests for it.  I am writing the code so getHypotenuse will only run if it is given valid vata.  Valid data is no negative numbers, no 0, no imaginary numbers, and only doubles will be inputs.

```
fun getHypotenuse (leg1: Double, leg2: Double) : Double{
return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(leg1,2.0)+Math.pow(leg2,2.0))}
```

The following function will check for valid inputs:

```
fun validLegs (leg1: Double, leg2: Double) : Boolean{
if(leg1<=0 ||leg2<=0)
    return false
return true}
```

Main method

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var leg1 = 3.0
var leg2 = 4.0

if(validLegs(leg1,leg2)){
    var aa=getHypotenuse(leg1,leg2)
    println("Hypotenuse is "+aa.toString())
}
else println("Triangle is a line or imaginary triangle")}
```

Test code

```
@Test
fun test_getHypotenuse_345_triangle() {
    val leg1 =3.0
    val leg2 =4.0
    val expected = 5.0
    val delta = .00001
    assertEquals(expected,getHypotenuse(leg1,leg2),.001)
}
```

I am not sure what else to test for in getHypotenuse.  I could write 3 more tests to cover all possible inputs but am not sure if it is necessary:
`getHypotenuse(3.1,5)`
`getHypotenuse(3.0,5.1)`
`getHypotenuse(3.1,5.1)`

I have read through the android developer tutorials, stackoverflow, and have read Android Test-Driven development by Tutorials.  It seems most of the examples show that the functions should check that the inputs are valid before any operation is performed on them.  I am going to have complex formulas that will only run if the inputs are valid.
I need to check that the complex formulas are accurate.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You test formulas are valid by comparing their output against known-good values--how else would a math formula be verified (short of writing a theorem prover)?

Comment: Should all 4 cases be run against getHypotenuse()?

Comment: You should also write test cases for `validLegs`. Personally I would include the validation in `getHypotenuse` and either throw a checked exception, or return an `Either<Double,ErrorMessage>` to avoid the possibility of someone calling the function without first validating the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There are no rules to say which tests need to be written.

In this example, the function is simple and continuous within its range.  The implementation can be "verified" by simply reading the code.  So the real purpose of the tests is to confirm your (or reviewer's) reading of the code.

So in this case, testing a couple of known cases<sup>1</sup> should be sufficient; e.g. [Pythagoras' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) tells us that if this is a right-angle triangle, and the opposite and adjacent edges are 3 and 4 respectively (or vice versa), then the hypotenuse should be 5.  So that represents two possible test-cases.  If you want more, there are other Pythagorean triangles.

Beyond that, you need tests for the edge cases, and for the error cases, and you are done.

If you want to be pedantic about it, you should also test for cases where the inputs are NaN and / or INF values.

But like I said at the start of my answer, there are no rules.  No (categorically) right way.  Use your own judgement.

---

<sup>1 - Pythagorean triangles / [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) are high-school level mathematics knowledge.  The point is that you need "correct" outputs that have been derived independently of the code you are testing.  Otherwise you could be testing an incorrect output against an incorrect expected output.</sup>